# OpenGL wglMakeCurrent() reports resources busy

Tags: c++, opengl

I initialize my code normally, and get a valid device / render context, and then store those two in a static object of type OpenGL_Display. When I then call the image update function from outside the DLL, the call to both
`wglGetCurrentContext()` as well as `wglGetCurrentDC()` return NULL.
When I call `wglMakeCurrent()` with the `HDC` and `HRC` stored in my class, `GetLastError()` will return error 170 (The requested resource is in use.)

I don't understand how the resource could be in use from any where. Note that the code runs fine from a .exe, so it has something to do with me calling it from a C# Application, or that it is in a DLL in the first place, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why those resources are busy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is returned when the context is active in another thread.

Most likely is that your creation/initialisation code does a `wglMakeCurrent()`, but does not set the context back to NULL before returning.

If the drawing then occurs on a different thread, it will be unable to set the context and will return ERROR_BUSY.

Comment: Nice, thank you a ton! That did it, now I got the live display working!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use OpenGL from a C# application (I assume .NET framework) then you should use [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.net/).